# Regex on multi-part field

Tags: regex

I have one input field that will represent a height in feet and inches. Users want an inout mask on the field as well, so when typed, it will separate the two halves of my 4 byte field with a slash; i.e. XX/XX.

The first XX is feet, and can basically be any number, although this height represents loading docks, so I suppose anything over 15 or 20 feet would be ridiculous.

The second XX are inches, and needs to be limited between 0 and 11. I thought I came up with what I needed with jquery masked input plug in, but i couldn't get it to allow a single digit in one of the XX columns, and I don't want to force the user to enter a leading 0.

I'm thinking this is probably pretty easy to knock out with reg ex...I'm sure someone here can prove me right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a [blog post](http://aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2014/03/02/regex_numeric_range/) about using regular expressions for validating number ranges. It's generally not recommended, but in this limited case perhaps it's okay.

If you assume that the first `XX` can be `0-30` (to be safe), you can use this:

```
(30|[0-2]\d)\|(0\d|11)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/WKNNgm72-6EHmfue)

Comment: Thanks! I will accept this as the answer a you got me 95% of the way there. In order to allow the user to enter a single digit in both sides of my 2 part field, I had to do create a custom mask as well as a little string manipulation on my field, before I applied the regex on it.

Comment: Glad it helped. To allow a single digit, you could also use a couple question marks: `(30|[0-2]?\d)\|(0?\d|11)`. Thanks for the up-vote and acceptance.